# searching for a substring of a string in c, then making a new string out of it

Tags: c, string, c-strings

C does not make this easy. I looked all over, found nothing.

I need to search a C string for a substring starting with "Sample: ", then create a new c string that consists of all the characters after that until the first newline.

In C++ I could do this in a heartbeat. Can a more experienced C programmer show me the way?

I'm sure i could do this by writing it out by hand, but surely there are SOME built-in functions that help?

Comment: Lookup strstr(), and maybe strchr() BTW: I can advise you to study the functions in the std libray thoroughly. There are not tha many functions, but when you need them you might remember their names.

Comment: why did i get a -1? out of curiousity...seems like a legitimate question to me

Comment: Probably because you complain and show no effort.

Comment: Not sure what effort was supposed to be shown, since the point of the question was to learn something about using built-in C functions, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) and [`strndup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) are your friends, just remember to free the output when you are done:

```
const char *input = "Hello Sample: This is a test\nTest";

const char *start = strstr(input, "Sample: ");

if (!start)
{
    // report error here
}

const char *end = strstr(start, "\n");
if (!end)
{
    // you have two options here. 
    // #1: use pure strdup on start and you have your output
    // #2: make this an error, and report it to the user.
}


int length = end - start;

char *output = strndup(start, length);

printf("%s", output); // Prints "Sample: This is a test"

free(output);
```

It isn't too hard if you know the right API calls.

Comment: I didn't realize you could subtract the char *s. That's awesome. That's the thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Aerovistae it has to do with how strings are stored in memory, as contiguous blocks of memory. So, If I have a pointer to index a of the memory, the difference between that pointer and the start of the block of memory is the length of the substrings.

Comment: @Aerovistae: If you search for the term "pointer arithmetic" you will find many explanations and examples.

Comment: Just don't forget to check for NULL returns from both calls to `strstr()` and do the appropriate thing.

Comment: @Richard: you're checking for `!start` a little too late (if it's NULL you can't use it in the `strstr()` call).